# Create Facebook Posts as Drafts via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, post

i'm asking here cause i have no more idea. I'm trying to post as a Facebook Page on the Pages Feed. That all works very fine. But now, i need to create Facebook Posts as a Draft. 
I've read nearly the whole Graph API Documentation but i didn't find a solution. I'm now able to publish scheduled, live and hidden Posts. But i have no idea how to publish a post as a Draft.

This is my working PHP Code

```
$PostObject->setPostMessage($Message);
$PostObject->setPostPlace($Post->getPostLocation());
$PostObject->setPostLink($Post->getPostLink());
$PostObject->setPostScheduledPublishTime($Post->getPostSheduledUnixtimestamp());
$PostObject->setPostAccessToken($Page->getPageAccessToken());
$PostObject->setPostTags($Post->getPostTagged());
$Response = $this->_facebookClient->post(
    '/' . $Page->getPageID() . "/feed",
    $PostObject->toArray()
);
```

Can anybody give me a hint? I'm using the actual Graph API in Version 2.9.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don’t think that is possible.

Comment: that is not good :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had quite the same task and got crazy about the bad documentation of the "draft" feature within the API.

First of all: it is possible!

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/#Creating - there's a parameter popping up in the "create" section named `unpublished_content_type`which can be `DRAFT`, `SCHEDULED` or `AD_POST`.

The good thing now is: this works for all edges (feed, photo, video). With multiple photos, you need to provide this with each single photo before creating the post itself.

and parameter `published` needs to be set to `false` every time of course.

I've tested with every edge successfully and posts are popping up under "Drafts" in the page!

Have fun.

Comment: Wow, this sounds really good, i will try it ASAP! Thanks a lot for your response!